# Matlab Write an Integer to a binary file

Tags: matlab

I have an `uint32` variable that needs to be stored as the first 4 bytes in a binary file.  How can I do that using MATLAB?

What I have tried is converting the integer to an array of bytes, and then store them byte by byte in the binary file, but I could not do that.

Comment: `fwrite`? http://www.mathworks.com.au/help/matlab/ref/fwrite.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Ben just said, use [`fwrite`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fwrite.html).  Supposing your `uint32` variable is stored in `A` which is of type `uint32`, and supposing you want to write to a file called `test.txt`, simply do this:

```
fid = fopen('test.txt', 'w'); %// Open test.txt for writing
fwrite(fid, A, 'uint32'); %// Write this single uint32 number to file
fclose(fid); %// Close the file to register the changes
```